# How can I modify the default locale in android?

Tags: android, locale, default

By default, the android system's default location is US and language is en.
But I want to set the default location to another country. So, the users will see their mother language when the first time startup android.

I have tried to modify the code(`/dalvik/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Locale.java`), changed the locale's default value. But no effect.

Can you tell me how to set the default location?

*I want to make an android image, then burn it to the device, when the android starts up the first time,  I want its os language is not English but another language.

Comment: Delete my answer because I misunderstood the question. To clarify for each reader: The question targets an customized android build (custom rom), not application based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for all you reply.

i have found the method to change the default language.

just modify the `file(build/core/Makefile)`.

set `PRODUCT_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` and `PRODUCT_DEFAULT_REGION` to what you want to set.

Comment: That line is something like: PRODUCT_DEFAULT_REGION="$(call default-locale-region,$(PRODUCT_LOCALES))" \ ------- What is a example value?!

Answer (score 2):

I make customer build via build/target/product/core.mk
Samples:

```
PRODUCT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES := \
    ro.config.notification_sound=OnTheHunt.ogg \
    ro.config.alarm_alert=Alarm_Classic.ogg \
    ro.config.ringtone=BirdLoop.ogg \
    persist.sys.language=zh \
    persist.sys.country=CN \
    persist.sys.timezone=Asia/Shanghai
```

This is what i do to make a simplified-chinese customer build.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.locale`

and use method `getISOcounty`, `getISOLanguage` etc...

to know more in detail go through
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: This is not really what he has asked for. He is basically trying to create his custom ROM with a custom default locale like WarrenFaith already mentioned.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
actually, i just want to modified the default value of locale.
not by calling an method.
that means:what i want is if no one has changed the locale, the default locale is not US but the locale which i want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked out this part?

```
 private Locale() {
   languageCode = "en"; //$NON-NLS-1$
   countryCode = "US"; //$NON-NLS-1$
   variantCode = ""; //$NON-NLS-1$
 }
```

It starts at line 212 in Locale.java. Is this the part where you've set your default values? If so then please post that bit up so I can check it out.

EDIT: Actually if you can post your whole Locale.java up on Pastebin. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: yes , i have modified it .
i have uploaded the Locale.java. http://pastebin.com/VF5zyktq

Comment: Odd you've done what I would've done. I will try to find a solution but this might take some time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to insert a local SIM before boot. But in my case the timezone wouldn't be set automagically not even then.

#### For lineage 18, first boot setup, custom build:

Add base locale as top on `PRODUCT_LOCALES` in `build/target/product/full_base.mk` like
`PRODUCT_LOCALES := de_DE`

To set the default timezone via makefiles didn't work for me, but it worked to hardcode it in the SetupWizard.
So change line 84 in `packages/apps/SetupWizard/src/org/lineageos/setupwizard/DateTimeActivity.java` from
`mCurrentTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();`
to:
`mCurrentTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam");`

Check first which timezones are at hand by browsing the list!